# posting scope variable through $http.post in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

```
$http.post('/#/college', $scope.userb) 
          .success(function(data, status) {
             console.log("Sent ok");
          })
          .error(function(data, status) {
             console.log("Error");
          })




  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlHyy.jpg
```

Is this the correct format/way to post my form data using http.post.?
    The above code always returns "error" in the console.
    please guide me to use http.post to post my form datathrough my controller.

---

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();



var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "abc@gmail.com",
        pass: "abc202"
    }
});
var rand, mailOptions, host, link;
app.get('/#/college',function(req,res){
        rand=Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 54);
    host=req.get('host');
    link="http://"+req.get('host')+"/verify?id="+rand;
    mailOptions={
        to : req.userb.counselloremail,
        subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
        html : "Hello,<br> Please Click on the link to verify your email.<br><a href="+link+">Click here to verify</a>" 
    }
    console.log(mailOptions);
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
     if(error){
            console.log(error);
        res.end("error");
     }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        res.end("sent");
         }
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

I am trying to access the email address from the scope variable and post it so that i may send a confirmation mail that he is successfully registered now. Also I am sending the code of my web.js file that receives the posted data and sends the mail.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the response, what are you doing in /#/college with that scope variable?

Comment: Where are you posting it to, the error callback will fire if the request fails. What does the endpoint do?

Comment: the `#` is out of place. You are posting to `/`, since the fragment part of the URL (i.e. everything after `#`) is meant to only be interpreted on the client. Was this what you meant to do? I'm guessing that the error is `HTTP 404 - Not found`

Comment: I removed the # but problem still remains

Comment: @AshutoshPradhan, what is the endpoint that you created on your server? And what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

That URL you are posting to is not going to be valid.

If you are posting to another route in your app, the URL would just be #/college.

I'm also a little worried that you don't have anything setup to receive a post request, like on a server or anything. Could you give some more detail about what you are trying to do and your setup?

Comment: OK, but where are you trying to post to. That URL, /#/college, what is that?

Comment: If $scope.userb is actually that email address (you can check it with console.log), your problem is in the /#/college endpoint, post the code or check where the request fails

Comment: $scope.userb.counselloremail is the actual email address i want to post.
and i replaced the "/#/college" with "/college" but the problem still remains

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataObject = {
      userid : LoginUserID
   };

 var responsePromise = $http.post(ApiAccessUrl+"/store/userstoreslist/", dataObject, {});
   responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer, status, headers, config)                
   {
       var outputDate=angular.fromJson(dataFromServer);
   });
    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("Error in fetching user store call!");
   });

 This is the correct way of sending data using http.post
```